# cpufreq governors : schedutil missing

Tags: resource-governor

In my linux machine, only only **performance** and **powersave** are avaliable. How I can enable **schedutil**?

```
available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
```

Answer (score 0):

I found we first have to make sure that our kernel support schedutil.

Check kernel support: Run the following command to check if the "schedutil" governor is available in your kernel:

```
grep -i schedutil /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

If the command returns a line with `CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_SCHEDUTIL=y`, it means the "**schedutil"** governor is enabled in the kernel configuration.
I use antix linux and after upgrading my kernel from **4.9.?** to **linux-headers-5.10.173-antix.1-amd64-smp**, **schedutil** can be enabled.